# Create Sets from columns using MDX

Tags: excel, mdx

I've got 8 columns of data ID, Language, LinkText1, LinkURL1, LinkText2, LinkURL2, LinkText3, and LinkURL3. In a pivot table I need to merge the contents from LinkText1, LinkText2, and LinkText3 into a single column of information.

```
ID          Language    LinkText1           LinkURL1    LinkText2   LinkURL2    LinkText3   LinkURL3
900-0025    Portuguese  VVR de validação    www         (blank)     (blank)     (blank)     (blank)
900-0026    Portuguese  VVR de validação    www         (blank)     (blank)     (blank)     (blank)
900-0023    Russian     Руководство         partner1    Загрузите   partner2    Форма       partner3
900-0030    Portuguese  resgate de vouchers www2        (blank)     (blank)     (blank)     (blank)
900-0028    Italian     Visualizzare        page1       modifiche   page2       (blank)     (blank)
900-0028    Korean      프로필에 나열된 회사  site1      나열된 응    site2       (blank)      (blank)
1000-0036   English     KB1                 support     KB3         support3    (blank)     (blank)
1000-0036   Japanese    内部使              support.jp  の異         support3.jp のトークン引  support4.jp
1000-0038   English     KB2                 support1    (blank)     (blank)     (blank)     (blank)
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
ID          Language        LinkText            LinkURL             
900-0025    Portuguese      VVR de validação    www             
900-0026    Portuguese      VVR de validação    www             
900-0023    Russian         Руководство         partner1                
900-0030    Portuguese      resgate de vouchers www2                
900-0028    Italian         Visualizzare        page1               
900-0028    Korean          프로필에 나열된 회사 site1               
1000-0036   English         KB1                 support             
1000-0036   Japanese        内部使              support.jp             
1000-0038   English         KB2                 support1                
900-0023    Russian         Загрузите           partner2                
900-0028    Italian         Emodifiche          page2               
900-0028    Korean          나열된 응            site2              
1000-0036   English         KB3                 support3                
1000-0036   Japanese        の異                support3.jp               
900-0023    Russian         Форма               partner3                
1000-0036   Japanese        のトークン引         support4.jp
```

Comment: Do you have some code or formulas that you have already attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: Do it with a formula in a column next to the pivot?

Comment: I've tried using multiple forms of a UNION in MDX to create a set, but that still gives me multiple columns in my pivot table. Not exactly sure how I would approach with a formula in a column next to the pivot table.

Comment: I like `mdx` - please show us the current script.